# link click area issue in IE with text shadow filter

Tags: css, menu, filter

Following menu, I expect entire area to be click-able, but IE it doesn't, reason is I'm using text shadow filter, if I remove `filter: dropshadow()` and apply `float:left;` my expectation will be set, any workaround to make this done.

HTML

```
<div><a href='#'>Home</a></div>    
<div><a href='#'>Contact us</a></div>    
<div><a href='#'>Feedback</a></div>    
<div><a href='#'>Products</a></div>
```

CSS

```
a{
  color:#f00; 
  font-size:15px;
  text-shadow: -1px -2px 2px #212121; 
  filter: dropshadow(color=#212121, offx=-1, offy=-2); 
  padding: 13px 0 0 16px; 
  display:block; 
  height:25px; 
  width:100%; 
  zoom:1; 
  line-height: 30px;  
}
div {
  height:40px; 
  padding-top:5px; 
  border:#999 solid 1px; 
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

Fiddle also for reference http://jsfiddle.net/eHgKs/

Answer (score 0):

many of the css doesn't work on IE

a simple work around as I prefer is to put an image of each of the link

I know it's not worth but still.